# How to translate, "not going to suggest"?

Tags: verb-choice

Attempting to translate:

> You’re not going to suggest buying back that robot?

The sentence is meaning that the one spoken to should not make such a suggestion.

I said:

> Du willst es nicht vorgeschlagen **werden**, dass du den Roboter zurückkaufst?

But 2 native German speakers corrected me with:

> Du willst es nicht vorschlagen, dass du den Roboter zurückkaufst?

However, I do find many examples of ["vorgeschlagen werden werden"](https://www.dwds.de/r/?corpus=bundestag&q=vorschlagen%20werden%20werden), albeit none in the negative. Is that important or is the original sentence a possible, correct translation?

Comment: Please clarify, what you consider *not* to negate in the English sentence. In my opinion, it is the expectation, i. e. the speaker does not expect this suggestion. This would translate to *nicht etwa vorschlagen, ....*

Comment: Did you realize that all the examples you found were "vor**ge**schlagen werden werden", which is a completely different thing?

Comment: No, I did not realize. Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure you understood them correctly? What you propose as "native German", sounds really off to my native ears. The "es" does not fit in there.

Comment: Yes, I was quite confused with this translation. planetmaker sorted it out well.

Comment: If 2 native speakers suggested "Du willst es nicht vorschlagen, dass du den Roboter zurückkaufst?" I don't know what to say. The sentence seems to the grammatically correct, but it's very far from a fluent writing style. The suggestion by planetmaker below is much more natural.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start your translation with the base phrase "going to do sth". It translates to "etwas tun werden" or "etwas tun wollen".

So the question "**You** are **not** going to XXX" translates to "**Du** wirst **(doch) nicht** XXX tun (wollen)?". The "doch" is somewhat optional and expresses surprise or incredulity. Now we simply have to plug in the remainder.

"You are not going to **suggest buying back that robot**?" and similar in German we get "Du wirst doch nicht **vorschlagen** (wollen)**, den Roboter zurückzukaufen**?"

Comment: That is the literal translation. But what a German speaker would actually say is usually "Soll ich den Roboter etwa zurückkaufen?" (Auxiliaries that express modality often map to *Modalpartikeln* in idiomatic German.)

Comment: The English sentence importantly associates a heavy degree of resistance to the act. "Soll ich den Roboter etwa zurückkaufen?" does not seem to convey the same resistance.

Comment: Oh, but it does! Our *Modalpartikeln* often express modality with the same intensity as much longer constructions in other languages do. Unfortunately, this is often not appreciated even among language teachers.